# Chrome caching and not updating svg

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, svg

It works as expected when you hover over it in dev panel or resize window.

But just changing value of polygon is not forcing svg to update.

How annoying.

How can this be fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/yyPvc/11/

```
var angle=10; code is working as it should. It works in other browsers.
```

Comment: check console for errors `Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="0;" `

Comment: i got it working after hacking but it's not what i want...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yyPvc/14/ hiding and showing main div to force redraw